# Determine the athletes who have arrived in one of the first three positions for each type of stage

Tags: sql

I have this query to solve:

> determine the athletes who have arrived in one of the first three positions for each type of stage.

I had thought of doing it like this but no athlete can find me.

```
SELECT c.name_cyclist
FROM arrival_order oa
JOIN tape s ON oa.tape_name = s.tape_name
JOIN cyclist c ON oa.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id
WHERE oa.order IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY c. name_cyclist
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT type) = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM stage);
```

The tables are:

- cyclist (cyclist_id: Int, name_cyclist: string, team: string of three
  letters, country: three-letter string)
- tape(_name: string, km: int, type: 'flat' or 'high_mountain' or 'medium_mountain' or 'chronometro_a_team' or 'chronometro_individual' or 'time trial')
- arrival_order (cyclist_id; tape_name, order: int): where cyclist_id (resp, tape_name) is an external key that refers to cyclist (resp, tape);

Comment: What does "no athlete can find me." mean?

Comment: Not sure about "(DISTINCT type) = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM stage)" because type is a string and COUNT(*) is an int.

Comment: i don't find no one athlete

Comment: Add `c.cyclist_id` in `group by` and check if query returns any record. Also there is no column like `c.name_cyclist`

Comment: I had written wrong on the table (name_cyclist) ... I added c.cyclist_id but nothing returns ...

Comment: @nicomp No that doesn't matter. `COUNT(DISTINCT varchar_field)` returns an `int`

Answer (score 0):

You have to also add grouping by stage `type` (or `tape_name`, whatever you call):

```
SELECT c.name_cyclist  
FROM arrival_order oa  
JOIN stage s ON oa.tape_name = s.tape_name  
JOIN cyclist c ON oa.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id  
WHERE oa.order IN (1, 2, 3)  
GROUP BY c. name_cyclist, s.type
HAVING COUNT (1) = (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT type) FROM stage);
```

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: Does it return without the `having` part?

Comment: yes, returns the cyclists who finished in the top three in all the stages

Comment: Thats good. Now, the number of rows for each cyclist should be equal to the number of stages, right?

Comment: well thats perfect. You can use this query as a subquery to get just the athletes. for example:  
`select name_cyclist  from (the_upper_query) as t group by t.name_cyclist`

Comment: ok but how can I find only those who are positioned in the top three in each type of stage?

Comment: But you've already done that in the `where` clause ...

Comment: yes I know, but with this I get the cyclists who have placed in the top 3 in ALL STAGES .... I need the cyclists who have placed in the top 3 in EVERY TYPE OF STAGE ...
.there must be a cyclist who finished in the top three in the flat, mountain, time trial, etc.

Comment: Ok, i edited my answer. So the condition is that the cyclist is 1st,2nd or 3rd in every **type** of stage, but not neccessarily in all stages, right?